# Azure hashing the sub claim in a JWT - how can I recreate the hashing logic?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, adfs

Azure ADFS is using a method to hash the sub claim of a JWT when using their oAuth2.0 capabilities as an IDP server.

The hash is made of the client id and a unique user identifier - I would like to recreate that hashing logic but can't find anywhere on Azure documentation that says how this hash logic works or if there is a way to unhash it from Azure / have it sent unhashed or any other suggestion that helps me be able to get this value on the front-end.

Comment: Hashing is one way. So you cant "unhash" it. Is there a reason why you need to recreate the same logic?

Comment: I need to use specifically the unique identifier passed in the sub of the JWT with another 3rd party tool to authenticate (the tool needs to have that unique identifier directly and also verify that it matches what it receives in the sub of the JWT)